# Get datas from local json file in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am modifying a repository I found on github and as you seen in code below the app uses API but it is inside the dart file. I copied that json data to '`questions.json`' file, now I want to do something like that (which is wrong of course) : 
`var json = 'assets/questions.json';`

Any help?

```
  @override
  Future<bool> getQuestions(
      {StreamedList<Question> questions,
      int number,
      Category category,
      QuestionDifficulty difficulty,
      QuestionType type}) async {

    const json = "{\"response_code\":0......here is the json data........}";

    final jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(json);

    final result = (jsonResponse['results'] as List).map((question) => QuestionModel.fromJson(question));

    questions.value = result.map((question) => Question.fromQuestionModel(question)).toList();

    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load your data from your assets folder, you need 2 things:

1) Make sure that file is included in your `pubspec.yaml` - refer to the yaml file's comment on how to do that.

2) Use the `rootBundle`. Something along the lines of:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

// code
var data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data.json');
```